# Match decimal as string to 0 in MongoDB without regex

Tags: regex, string, mongodb, decimal

I have a MongoDB collection where decimal numbers are stored as `string`. I need to find all those items that have one of such fields, `quantity`, equal to `0`. Thus when looking for `0` I am actually looking for the strings:

```
"0"
"0.0"
"0.00"
```

...
and so on

I tried to use `$toInt` as follows

```
db.MyCollection.find({$toInt(Product.Quantity): 0})
```

but the query is flagged as wrong, it does not even get executed

After some digging I finally found the solution using regex:

```
db.MyCollection.find({"Product.Quantity": {$regex: "^0+$|^0+(\.0+)"}})
```

which indeed works but it I am sure that there is a more straightforward solution, it cannot be so utterly complex. Does anybody have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

[Live](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5oqmwvYJnkQ)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $eq: [
        {
          "$convert": {
            "input": "$key",
            "to": "double",
            "onError": "$key",
            "onNull": "$key"
          }
        },
        0
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Just replace `key` by your field.

[On this example,](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L405DQ_o4Ki) you can see how it is operating under the hood.

Or using find

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
      $eq: [
        {
          "$convert": {
            "input": "$key",
            "to": "double",
            "onError": "$key",
            "onNull": "$key"
          }
        },
        0
      ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes it works, I thoguht it can be done with a simple find instead of using aggregate

Comment: @CiccioMiami Sure, aggregate/match and find are equivalent. updated :-)  The reason to choose aggregation in the first place is it's more powerful, but no difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regex is convenient to search for numbers in string format. You could simplify the regex a bit:

`db.MyCollection.find({"Product.Quantity": {$regex: "^0(\.0+)?$"}})`

Explanation of regex:

- `^` ... `$` - anchor at the beginning and end
- `0` - expect a `0`
- `(\.0+)?` - followed by optional `.0`, `.00`, etc